# Filtering with multiple parameters with Linq or stored procedure

Tags: sql, linq, search, stored-procedures

Is there a better way to implement filtering with multiple parameters (parameters with values only) without using multiple `if` statements:

```
IQueryable<vw_GetAllSalesInvoice> query = null;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(invoiceNumber) && status == 0 && !fromDate.HasValue && !toDate.HasValue)
    query = from x in _context.vw_GetAllSalesInvoice select x;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(invoiceNumber) && status == 0 && !fromDate.HasValue && !toDate.HasValue)
    query = from x in _context.vw_GetAllSalesInvoice 
            where x.CustomerName.Contains(customerName) 
            select x;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(invoiceNumber) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerName) && status == 0 && !fromDate.HasValue && !toDate.HasValue)
    query = from x in _context.vw_GetAllSalesInvoice 
            where x.InvoiceNumber.Contains(invoiceNumber) 
            select x;

if (status != 0 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(invoiceNumber) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerName) && !fromDate.HasValue && !toDate.HasValue)
    query = from x in _context.vw_GetAllSalesInvoice 
            where x.Status == status 
            select x;

if (fromDate.HasValue && toDate.HasValue && status == 0 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(invoiceNumber) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerName))
    query = from x in _context.vw_GetAllSalesInvoice 
            where x.InvoiceDate >= fromDate && x.InvoiceDate <= toDate 
            select x;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(invoiceNumber) && status == 0 && !fromDate.HasValue && !toDate.HasValue)
    query = from x in _context.vw_GetAllSalesInvoice 
            where x.CustomerName.Contains(customerName) && x.InvoiceNumber.Contains(invoiceNumber) 
            select x;
```

I believe there will be a more simpler way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditions on the variables as well as on the properties of `x` with a combination of `&&` and `||` and build your query like this:

```
IQueryable<vw_GetAllSalesInvoice> query = from x in _context.vw_GetAllSalesInvoice where 
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerName) || x.CustomerName.Contains(customerName)) && 
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(invoiceNumber) || x.InvoiceNumber.Contains(invoiceNumber)) && 
    (status == 0 || x.Status == status) && 
    ((!fromDate.HasValue || !toDate.HasValue) && x.InvoiceDate >= fromDate && x.InvoiceDate <= toDate)
    select x;
```

Since `||` is short-circuit, `x.CustomerName.Contains(customerName)` will only be evalulated if `customerName` is not null and not an empty string - and the rest is true for all other conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can cascade queries like this:

```
IQueryable<vw_GetAllSalesInvoice> query = _context.vw_GetAllSalesInvoice;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerName)
    query = from x in query
            where x.CustomerName.Contains(customerName) 
            select x;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(invoiceNumber))
    query = from x in query 
            where x.InvoiceNumber.Contains(invoiceNumber)
            select x;

if (status != 0)
    query = from x in query
            where x.Status == status 
            select x;

if (fromDate.HasValue)
    query = from x in query 
            where x.InvoiceDate >= fromDate && x.InvoiceDate <= toDate 
            select x;
```

If you don't mind using the method syntax, it can be even shorter:

```
IQueryable<vw_GetAllSalesInvoice> query = _context.vw_GetAllSalesInvoice;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerName)
    query = query.Where(x => x.CustomerName.Contains(customerName));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(invoiceNumber))
    query = query.Where(x => x.InvoiceNumber.Contains(invoiceNumber));

if (status != 0)
    query = query.Where(x => x.Status == status);

if (fromDate.HasValue)
    query = query.Where(x => x.InvoiceDate >= fromDate && 
                             x.InvoiceDate <= toDate);
```